# Testing on iOS 6 with Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to be test my app on my ipad iOS 6 device. I have been told to upgrade my Snow Leopard 10.6.8 to Mountain Lion. This will allow me to upgrade XCode 3.2 to XCode 4. But I cannot upgrade to Lion due to several issues. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: jailbreaking ipad u mean? i would loose access to itunes?

Comment: This is one of the typical stupid questions that should be googled.

Comment: Other than jailbreak - because it seems like a stretch